# Help with a Partial derivative problem

Tags: calculus

Could someone please help me with this problem? Thanks.

An iso curve of a function $f(x,y)$ is the path satisfying $f(x,y) = c$, where $c$ is a given value. Consider a function $f(x, y)$, which is defined for $x\in(-\infty,\infty)$ and $y\in(0,\infty)$. The partial derivatives of $f(x,y)$ are given by

$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=f_x(x,y)=4e^{4e}y^2$ and $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}=f_y(x,y)=2e^{4e}y$

We assume that the implicit function $y = g(x)$ defined by the isoquant (that is, the iso curve) exists, and that the derivative of $g(x)$ exists. Find the analytical form of $g(x)$ that passes through
the point $(0,2)$.

Comment: Please don't use pictures of the question

Comment: Many thanks. I have typed out the question in a proper way.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain my solution. Just for the next time, please mention your attempts or thoughts about your question. Also, I think the power of $e$ is a multiple of $x$.

As $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 4e^{4x}y^2$, we have :

$$ f = e^{4x}y^2 + h(y).$$

on the other hand $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=2e^{4x}y$.

so we have that $h$ is a constant function $c_0$.

Now, if we are dealing with a $c$, where for every point $(x_0,y_0)$ the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $y$ does not vanish the by the implicit function theorem we have around those points $y$ can be shown locally as a function of $x$ and the derivative of that function, let's call it $g$,  equals to :

$$ \frac{dg}{dx}= -\frac{\partial_{x} f}{\partial_{y} f}.$$

so by the above, we have that :

$$ \frac{dg}{dx} = -2g.$$

Thus $g(x) = e^{-2x}+C_0$. In our case at the point $(0,2)$, $C_0 =1$.